# How to create editable sections in wordpress?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I am making a website for a friend and he doesn't know how to code so I decided to make him a WordPress website which is new to me. I wanna make a homepage that has different sections (About us section, photo gallery section, etc). he might want to change the about us section later in the future or add pictures in the galley. whats the best way to do this?

I have thought about making posts for each section (an about us post and he could just edit it whenever he wants to change the about us section) does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would recommend.

Use a plugin called [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/).

This will allow you to build out the admin and have different fields for each section.  You could have an editable area [with a editor](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/wysiwyg-editor/) for the about us section.  You could use a [Repeater Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) for the gallery, and [much more](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/).

Once you have all the fields in the admin, you just need to pull all the data into your homepage template.  This is pretty straight forward and there is good documentation [with examples](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/code-examples/).

This is one of the few plugins I recommend, but when it comes adding custom fields it doesn't make sense to not use it.

Comment: Why not just use static front page and edit it with Gutenberg?

Comment: Because my way gives full control of the content and layout and is not held down by the limitations of Gutenberg.

Comment: And yet Gutenberg is built in and will be much easier to use for WP beginner. Also plugin recommendations are not very welcome in here, I guess ;)

Comment: The OP asked "whats the best way to do this" not what way is built in

Comment: and you certainly haven’t proved that your solution is the best... I love ACF, but this time it’s just overkill... You tell a beginner to implement his own temple ta with repeater and elastic field instead of using features of built in editor...

Comment: soo what's the best way??

Comment: My opinion is using ACF will give the most control and is easiest to manage.  Gutenberg isn't very easy to use when it comes to complex layouts.

Comment: alright do you have any tutorials i could follow cause i have no idea how to use ACF?

Comment: I would suggest looking into both methods before you go down one path.  Find the one you like and then look into it.  There are a ton of tutorials on here and elsewhere for either.

Comment: FYI - you need WP version 5+ for the Gutenburg editor

Comment: i think the ACF plugin looks good but i am not sure how to use it

Comment: Start here - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started-with-acf/  Learn how to use it and it will change how you use WP :)

Comment: Absolutely good luck!